# "openssl dgst -sha1" producing an extraneous "(stdin)= " prefix and trailing newline

Tags: openssl, stdin

If you run this command on your Unix

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1
```

You will get this output:

```
(stdin)= 0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33
```

(followed by a newline).

How can I force openssl to not show the `(stdin)=` prefix, and avoid the trailing newline?

Comment: @MarkDavidson Hmm, interesting. Are you sure it doesn't even append a newline?

Answer (score 41):

Raw binary format does not add any extraneous output.
Output as binary then convert to hex:

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | xxd -p
```

Will give you this:

```
0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33
```

This method should be future-proof in case someone decides to change the textual output format again. I'm sure they will fix the prefix to be "SHA1(stdin)= " to be consistent with that of a file input.

I can't believe that they changed this! I wonder how many scripts were broken.

Comment: It will only output 20-30 octets per line (or 40-60 characters). For SHA-256 checksum, this is not enough sometimes. Use the `-c 256` option to extend it to 256 octets per line.

Comment: Nice solution but do you have any idea what's the usage of that prefix?

Answer (score 17):

I observe this behavior under OpenSSL 1.0.0e on Ubuntu 11.10, whereas OpenSSL 0.9.8k and 0.9.8t output just the hash. OpenSSL's command line is not designed to be flexible, it's more of a quick-and-dirty way to perform cryptographic calculations from the command line.

If you want to use OpenSSL, filter the output:

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //'
```

On Linux (with GNU tools or BusyBox), you can use [`sha1sum`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sha1sum), which doesn't require OpenSSL to be installed and has a stable output format. It always prints a file name, so strip that off.

```
echo -n "foo" | sha1sum | sed 's/ .*//'
```

On BSD systems including OSX, you can use [`sha1`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sha1&sektion=1).

```
echo -n "foo" | sha1 -q
```

All of these output the checksum in hexadecimal followed by a newline. Text under unix systems always consists of a sequence of lines, and each line ends with a newline character. If you store the output of the command in a shell variable, the final newline is stripped off.

```
digest=$(echo -n "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //')
```

If you need to pipe the input into a program that requires a checksum with no final newline (which is really rare), strip off the newline.

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //' | tr -d '\n' | unusual_program
```

Comment: this is the perfect situation => copy & paste solution map. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here's another alternative:

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl sha1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I know the question asks with this specific format, however, if someone tries to extend this to include filenames, it could break if the filename has spaces in it. Just a heads up for other people who land here.

Comment: A slight change to this will resolve that issue: `echo -n "foo" | openssl sha1 | awk '{ print $NF }'` . This will also work with the openssl that comes with macOS (LibreSSL).

Comment: @dpk That will not resolve the space issue still

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it using bash built-ins instead of pipes, awk, sed, tr, cut, etc:

```
output="$(openssl sha1 <(printf foo))"; echo ${output/* }
```